# Pass multiple parameters/arguments to target

Tags: cakebuild

I've got a target `Release-Prepare` taking the version as an argument:

```
var version = Argument("version", "1.0.0.0");

Task ("Release-Prepare")
    .Does (() => {
        // Compute the package version
        var gitCommitHash = GitLogTip(projectDir).Sha;
        var gitVersion = gitCommitHash?.Substring(0, 8) ?? "Unknown";
        var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        var packageVersion = $"{version}-{gitVersion}-{currentDateTime}";
        Information(packageVersion);

        // Versions having to be modified in *.csproj
        var versionXPath = "/Project/PropertyGroup/Version";
        var assemblyVersionXPath = "/Project/PropertyGroup/AssemblyVersion";
        var fileVersionXPath = "/Project/PropertyGroup/FileVersion";

        // Set versions for all projects (excpet testing)
        var projectFilePaths = GetFiles("./**/*.csproj");
        foreach(var projectFilePath in projectFilePaths) {
            if(projectFilePath.FullPath.Contains("Tests")){
                // Do not version test projects
                continue;
            }

            XmlPoke(projectFilePath, versionXPath, packageVersion);
            XmlPoke(projectFilePath, assemblyVersionXPath, version);
            XmlPoke(projectFilePath, fileVersionXPath, version);
        }
    });
```

Executing the target without parameters works fine:

```
PS E:\dev\Sppd.TeamTuner> powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File build.ps1 -script "e:\dev\Sppd.TeamTuner\build.cake" -target "Release-Prepare" -verbosity normal
Preparing to run build script...
Running build script...

========================================
Release-Prepare
========================================
1.0.0.0-af9d218d-20191125093743

Task                          Duration
--------------------------------------------------
Release-Prepare               00:00:02.3258569
--------------------------------------------------
Total:                        00:00:02.3258569
```

But I can't figure out how to pass the target AND the version using a PowerShell command. I've tried:

- `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File build.ps1 -script "e:\dev\Sppd.TeamTuner\build.cake" -target "Release-Prepare" -version="1.2.3.4" -verbosity normal` -> Error: Argument value is not a valid boolean value.
- `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File build.ps1 -script "e:\dev\Sppd.TeamTuner\build.cake" -ScriptArgs '--target=Release-Prepare','--version=1.3.1.2' -verbosity normal` -> Error: The target 'Release-Prepare,--version=1.3.1.2' was not found.

I've tried all permutations of `-ScriptArgs '--target=Release-Prepare','--version=1.3.1.2'` I could think of (single dash, space/comma, single/double quotes. But everything I've tried resulted in cake intzerpreting as a single command.

How do ScriptArgs have to be specified to work for multiple parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are using the latest bootstrapper file, which is available from here:

https://cakebuild.net/download/bootstrapper/windows

**NOTE:** If this is not the case, then the way that the arguments are parsed and sent to Cake might be different than what I am showing here.

You can download this using:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://cakebuild.net/download/bootstrapper/windows -OutFile build.ps1
```

As mentioned [here](https://cakebuild.net/docs/tutorials/setting-up-a-new-project).

With that in place, let's use the following build.cake file:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ARGUMENTS
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var target = Argument("target", "Default");
var configuration = Argument("configuration", "Release");
var version = Argument("applicationVersion", "1.0.0.0");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SETUP / TEARDOWN
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Setup(ctx =>
{
   // Executed BEFORE the first task.
   Information("Running tasks...");
});

Teardown(ctx =>
{
   // Executed AFTER the last task.
   Information("Finished running tasks.");
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TASKS
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Task("Default")
.Does(() => {
   Information("Configuration: {0}", configuration);
   Information("Target: {0}", target);
   Information("Version: {0}", version);
});

Task("Release-Prepare")
   .Does(() =>
{
   Information("Configuration: {0}", configuration);
   Information("Target: {0}", target);
   Information("Version: {0}", version);
});

RunTarget(target);
```

If we run this with no arguments, we will get this as the output:

```
========================================
Default
========================================
Configuration: Release
Target: Default
Version: 1.0.0.0
```

However, if we run the following:

```
.\build.ps1 --target=Release-Prepare --configuration=Debug --applicationVersion=2.2.2.2
```

We will get:

```
========================================
Release-Prepare
========================================
Configuration: Debug
Target: Release-Prepare
Version: 2.2.2.2
```

One thing to mention compared to what you have...

The `version` argument is already one that is reserved by the Cake.exe directly, i.e. running:

```
cake.exe --version
```

Will output the version number of Cake itself.  That is why I switched to using `applicationVersion` as the argument name, rather than version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked (after having updated the bootstrapping file)! My main issue was that I was using the reserved version keyword and that I didn't relaize it with the message 'Error: Argument value is not a valid boolean value.'

Comment: If using -ScriptArgs then the syntax would be .\build.ps1 -Target 'Release-Prepare' -ScriptArgs '--configuration="Debug" --applicationVersion="2.2.2.2"' observ single quotes user for PowerShell arguments as then value is treated constants and won't do PowerShell variable interpolation.